# Is there any new good source for navigation in react-native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am new in `react-native` and I have many problems in using navigation libraries and their options. I tried to use `Wix v1`, `Wix v2` and `react-navigation` but in each of them I had a lot of errors and it took me a lot of time.I could overcome some of them but not completely. It made me frustrated. Because I cannot make progress without navigation, please someone save my life and introduce me some new documentation or give me some advices on this. For example I have tried `react-navigation` and I built a project with react-native version `0.5`8 and I did like Facebook documentation but I got the error `navigation has deprecated!`.

Answer (score 2):

React Navigation isn't your only option for routing and navigation in React Native.

The best libraries for navigations which I personally prefer are :

- `react-native-router-flux`: this library is very popular and best in market which is  based on React Navigation & provides you with a different API's to interact with it. [Documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)
- `react-native-navigation`: uses the underlying native APIs on iOS and Android, this is a popular alternative to React Navigation which you already tried. [Documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

You can also read a detailed article on medium [here](https://medium.com/osedea/react-native-navigation-solutions-in-2018-6ff1dd7f6d20) which compares different navigation libraries and features and other aspects.

Also you can check [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976957/react-native-which-navigator-should-i-use) raised by react-native enthusiasts.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think Wix documentation is hard to understand for beginners.

Comment: your welcome :) I would appreciate if you accept my answer so that other users find it useful as well

Answer (score 2):

Most popular and stable react native navigation lib is react-navigation. Anyway there are few Alternatives

1. [Native Navigation](http://airbnb.io/native-navigation/)
2. [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)
3. [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)
4. [react-router-native](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-native)

The decision is up to you

Comment: Thank you Niroshan.